# Kotlin multiple class for data storage

Tags: kotlin

I am developing a simple Android app, that will display an icon of a vehicle and the user can click on the icon to display the vehicle information. I want to load the data dynamically when I build the app i.e. the data will come from an external source including the picture for the icon.

I am new to Kotlin and not sure what to search for to understand a suitable solution. What is the correct way to define the data, is it best to create an class as below then create an array of the class (not sure if this is possible)

```
public class VehicleSpec()
{
var OEM: String? = null
var ModelName: String? = null
var EngineSize: String? = null
}
```

Or would be better to create a multiple dimension array and then link the data to the cells?

```
var VehicleSpec = arrayOf(20,20)
VehicleSpec[0][0] = Null //OEM
VehicleSpec[0][1] = Null //ModelName
VehicleSpec[0][2] = Null //EngineSize
```

What is the best way to set up the data storage, is there any good references to understand how this should be setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to define the data, is it best to create an class as below then create an array of the class

Using an array for the properties of an object is not making the full use of the type safety you have in Kotlin (and even Java for that matter).
If what you want to express is multiple properties of an object, then you should use a **class** to define those properties. This is especially true if the properties have different types.

There is no performance difference between an array and a class, because you'll get a reference to the heap in both cases. You could save on performance only if you convert your multi-dimensional array approach to a single-dimension array with smart indexing. Most of the time, you should not consider this option unless you are handling a lot of data and if you know that performance is an issue at this specific level.

> (not sure if this is possible)

Defining lists/arrays of classes is definitely possible.

Usually, for classes that are only used as data containers, you should prefer [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), because they give you useful methods for free, and these methods totally make sense for simple "data bags" like in your case (equals, hashcode, component access, etc.).

```
data class Vehicle(
   val OEM: String,
   val ModelName: String,
   val EngineSize: String
)
```

Also, I suggest using `val` instead of `var` as much as possible. Immutability is more idiomatic in Kotlin.

Last but not least, prefer non-null values to null values if you know a value must always be present. If there are valid cases where the value is absent, you should use null instead of a placeholder value like empty string or -1.

Answer (score 2):

First at all, using the "class aprocah" makes it easy for you to understand and give you the full benefits of the language itself... so dont dry to save data in an array .. let the compiler handle those stuff.

Secondly i suggest you have maybe two types (and use data classes ;-) )

```
data class VehicleListEntry(
  val id: Long,
  val name: String
)
```

and

```
data class VehicleSpec(
  val id: Long,
  val oem: String = "",
  val modelName: String = "",
  val engineSize: String = ""
)
```

from my perspective try to avoid null values whenever possible.
So if you have strings - which you are display only - use empty strings instead of null.

and now have a Model to store your data

```
class VehicleModel() {
  private val specs: MutableMap<Long, VehicleSpec> = mutableMapOf()
  private var entries: List<VehicleListEntry> = listOf()

  fun getSpec(id: Long) = specs[id]
  fun addSpec(spec: VehicleSpec) = specs[spec.id] = spec
  fun getEntries(): List<VehicleListEntry> = entries
  fun setEntries(data: List<VehicleListEntry>)  {
    entries = data.toMutableList()
  }

}
```

You could also use a data class for your model which looks like

```
data class VehicleModel(
  val specs: MutableMap<Long, VehicleSpec> = mutableMapOf(),
  var entries: List<VehicleListEntry> = listOf()
)
```

And last but not least a controller for getting stuff together

```
class VehicleController() {
  private val model = VehicleModel()

  init{
     // TODO get the entries list together
  }

  fun getEntries() = model.entries

  fun getSpec(id: Long) : VehicleSpec? {
     // TODO load the data from external source (or check the model first)
     // TODO store the data into the model
     // TODO return result
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the very detailed overview, that is a great help as still trying to convert by Python thinking brain into Kotlin

Comment: oh that will be fun :D .. i try to avoid the other way around ;-)